# jQuery select element by XPath

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I have an XPath selector. How can I get the elements matching that selector using jQuery?

I've seen https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript but it doesn't use jQuery, and it seems a little too verbose, and I suppose it's not cross-browser.

Also, this http://jsfiddle.net/CJRmk/ doesn't seem to work.

```js
alert($("//a").length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="a1.php"></a>
<a href="a2.php"></a>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`document.evaluate()` (DOM Level 3 XPath) is supported in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera - the only major browser missing is MSIE. Nevertheless, jQuery supports basic XPath expressions: http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#XPath_Selectors (moved into a plugin in the current jQuery version, see https://plugins.jquery.com/xpath/). It simply converts XPath expressions into equivalent CSS selectors however.

Comment: It's an old version of jQuery API for selectors

Comment: @Karolis: You are right, looks like this functionality has been moved into a plugin. I edited my answer to add this information.

Answer (score 163):

If you are debugging or similar - In chrome developer tools, you can simply use

```
$x('/html/.//div[@id="text"]')
```

Comment: @GregT ... and Firefox

Comment: @AloisMahdal, it looks like it's a Firebug thing (not 100% sure that it isn't also part of Firefox). [Documentation on Firebug's site](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/$x). It's also just shorthand for `document.evaluate()`, which @WladimirPalant mentioned.

Comment: Firefox developer tools [implement it as well](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/206205dd8bd1/toolkit/devtools/webconsole/utils.js#l1559). And sure enough, it's a very simple convenience wrapper around `document.evaluate()`. [More info on the helper commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Helper_commands)

Comment: And for select and use functions on it, this does not work: `$x('/html/.//div[@id="text"]').hide();` must use instead this: `$($x('/html/.//div[@id="text"]')).hide();`

Comment: Note that `$x()` is NOT jQuery. It is returning HTML DOM. `.hide()` is a jQuery function, so you need to wrap the HTML DOM in a `$()` to access jQuery functions, just like if you used any other native JS DOM functions.

Comment: this selects the element. How do i set the value into it?

Answer (score 27):

First create an xpath selector function.

```
function _x(STR_XPATH) {
    var xresult = document.evaluate(STR_XPATH, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var xnodes = [];
    var xres;
    while (xres = xresult.iterateNext()) {
        xnodes.push(xres);
    }

    return xnodes;
}
```

To use the xpath selector with jquery, you can do like this:

```
$(_x('/html/.//div[@id="text"]')).attr('id', 'modified-text');
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: I think this wont works if document uses namespace and in IE10-11 (XPath not supported).

Comment: Thanks, I have used your _x() function in Behat/Mink code to fix find('xpath', 'xpath expression')'s unsufficient results in some situations.