# can action builder solve hovered elements?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

Currently, and often I have elements on a page that become visible when hovered.

action builder sounded promising, but seems to require elements found beforehand, not during an operation.

This won't work...

```
page.driver.browser.action.
  move_to(find(:xpath, './/span[text()="Test"]')).
  move_to(find(:xpath, ".//span[text()="Test"]]/../a[@title="Hidden Thing to click"]')).
  click(find(:xpath, ".//span[text()="Test"]]/../a[@title="Hidden Thing to click"]')).
  perform
```

and pre-assignments will fail for those elements that are hidden

```
elem1 = find(:xpath, './/span[text()="Test"]') #ok
elem2 = find(:xpath, ".//span[text()="Test"]]/../a[@title="Hidden Thing to click"]') #ElementNotFound
page.driver.browser.action.
  move_to(elem1).
  move_to(elem2).
  click(elem2).
  perform
```

Maybe the real question is a sure fire way to find the onhover javascript, it seems well hidden on some pages.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does Capybara `hover` method not work for you?

```
find(:xpath, './/span[text()="Test"]').hover
find(:xpath, ".//span[text()="Test"]]/../a[@title="Hidden Thing to click"]').click
```

although I'd probably rewrite that something like

```
span = find(:xpath, './/span[text()="Test"]')
span.hover
span.find(:xpath, '../a[@title="Hidden Thing to click"]').click
```

Comment: How the common sense solution often alludes us. - George Carlin

Comment: Thomas you're awesome!  Thanks

Comment: @TangibleDream You're welcome, and if you're using the latest Capybara `hover` returns the object it's called on so you could chain it all if wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a mouseenter event which which will make it visible, then get it with a selector.

First you need access to a selenium driver object (maybe your `page.driver` or (`page.driver.browser`)

```
<driver>.execute_script <<-JS
  $("<some_selector>").trigger("mouseenter")
JS
```

note this assumes jquery is running on the webpage. You can rewrite it in plain js otherwise.

Comment: This threw a unknown error, is my syntax off  ```we = find(:xpath, '//blah```  and ```execute_script ("$(#{we}).trigger(\"mouseenter\")")```

Comment: you haven't defined the  `we` variable as something you can pass to javascript. The argument to the jquery selector is a string, so you'd interpolate it like `$('#{css_selector}')` see [javascript-use-xpath-in-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243661/javascript-use-xpath-in-jquery)

Comment: can i do an xpath selector instead?

Comment: see [is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-using-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver)