# Unable to perform drag and drop with Selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, drag-and-drop

I am struggling to perform drag and drop or click and hold actions with Selenium in python on private web app.

I try to reproduce my mistake on a public exemple here : 
http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop

Below is my basic piece of code for drag and drop / click and hold

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop')
dragged = driver.find_element(By.ID, "column-a")
dropped = driver.find_element(By.ID, "column-b")

#Drag and drop

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.drag_and_drop(dragged, dropped).perform() 
#column A is selected but not dragged

#Click and hold
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(dragged).click_and_hold().move_to_element(dropped).release().perform()
#Same result : column a is selected but not dragged
```

Searching through stackoverflow I came across a "solution" for the public exemple using javascript.
[How to simulate HTML5 Drag and Drop in Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381233/how-to-simulate-html5-drag-and-drop-in-selenium-webdriver)

```
import os
with open(os.path.abspath('C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/AutoTestIntro/drag_and_drop_helper.js'), 'r') as js_file:
    line = js_file.readline()
    script = ''
    while line:
        script += line 
        line = js_file.readline()

driver.execute_script(script+"$('#column-a').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#column-b'});")
```

This perfectly work directly in python but required to that dragged and dropped elements have ids. This is not the case on the private project I am currently working on.

Is there anything I am doing wrong with Selenium ? 
Is there any workaround in JS to specify xpath instead of id ?

Comment: Is the destination of the "dragged element" below or above the original position?

Comment: They are exactly on the same level in the exemple provided.

Comment: Post the html of the element you are needing to get. They are using css selectors, here is a list.  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Hi Jortega, thanks for your answer but I don't think I understand what you mean. Everything is present in this demo website provided in my exemple : http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop

I try to select using id, css selector, xpath.... none is working. Can you try on the demo website ?

Comment: If you can provide the html we can build the xpath you need in CSS. I have not been able to get the helper function `simulateDragDrop` to accept xpath.... without totally rebuilding it.

Comment: Sadlly I can't provide the html for my personnal project. And it's for test automation, so it will have to be rebuild every time :(

Comment: See this post for help with using css selectors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243661/javascript-use-xpath-in-jquery?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came across an answer !!!

See below :

https://gist.github.com/florentbr/60ef7cb8d9b1ae690cafc82aad52da73

I use the function from drag-drop.min.js

Here a short exemple in python :

```
JS_DRAG_AND_DROP = "function h(a,b,c,d){var k=l.createEvent('DragEvent');k.initMouseEvent(b,!0,!0,l.defaultView,0,0,0,m,n,w,x,y,!1,0,null);Object.setPrototypeOf(k,null);k.dataTransfer=g;Object.setPrototypeOf(k,DragEvent.prototype);a.dispatchEvent(k);setTimeout(d,c)}var a=arguments,c=a[0],d=a[1],q=a[2]||0,r=a[3]||0,t=a[4]||1;a=a[5]||'';var x='alt'===a||'\ue00a'===a,w='ctrl'===a||'\ue009'===a,y='shift'===a||'\ue008'===a,l=c.ownerDocument;a=c.getBoundingClientRect();var e=d?d.getBoundingClientRect():a,m=a.left+a.width/2,n=a.top+a.height/2,u=e.left+(q?q:e.width/2),v=e.top+(r?r:e.height/2),p=l.elementFromPoint(m,n),f=l.elementFromPoint(u,v);for(d=p;d&&!d.draggable;)d=d.parentElement;if(!d||!c.contains(p))throw c=Error('source element is not interactable/draggable'),c.code=15,c;if(!f)throw c=Error('target element is not interactable'),c.code=15,c;var g={constructor:DataTransfer,effectAllowed:null,dropEffect:null,types:[],files:Object.setPrototypeOf([],null),_items:Object.setPrototypeOf([],{add:function(a,b){this[this.length]={_data:''+_data,kind:'string',type:b,getAsFile:function(){},getAsString:function(a){a(this._data)}};g.types.push(b)},remove:function(a){Array.prototype.splice.call(this,a&65535,1);g.types.splice(a&65535,1)},clear:function(a,b){this.length=0;g.types.length=0}}),setData:function(a,b){this.clearData(a);this._items.add(b,a)},getData:function(a){for(var b=this._items.length;b--&&this._items[b].type!==a;);return 0<=b?this._items[b]._data:null},clearData:function(a){for(var b=this._items.length;b--&&this._items[b].type!==a;);this._items.remove(b)},setDragImage:function(a){}};'items'in DataTransfer.prototype&&(g.items=g._items);e=f.getBoundingClientRect();h(p,'dragstart',t,function(){var a=f.getBoundingClientRect();m=a.left+u-e.left;n=a.top+v-e.top;h(f,'dragenter',1,function(){h(f,'dragover',t,function(){f=l.elementFromPoint(m,n);h(f,'drop',1,function(){h(p,'dragend',1,function(){})})})})})"

def drag_and_drop(driver, source, target=None, offsetX=0, offsetY=0, delay=25, key=None) :
  driver.execute_script(JS_DRAG_AND_DROP, source, target, offsetX, offsetY, delay, key)
  time.sleep(delay * 2 / 1000)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop")


# drag and drop Glass
source = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='column-a']")
target = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='column-b']")
drag_and_drop(driver, source, target)
```

Comment: I think your JS_DRAG_AND_DROP function has a small error: 
in the _items.add function you want to set _data to ' '+a, and not to _data as this does not exist and throws an error
---

`add:function(a,b){
    this[this.length]={
        _data:''+a,
        kind:'string',
        type:b,
        getAsFile:function(){},
        getAsString:function(a){
            a(this._data)
        }
    };
    g.types.push(b)
},`
---
and maybe you could do a multiline string

Answer (score 1):

i did some reasearch around this issue and so far found only one way to solve it with pure python, meaning no JS script or stuff like that by using pyautogui.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import pyautogui

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop')
# ## driver.maximize_window()   - can work in full screen mode, but it will look a bit off center when drag and
# dropping the items ###
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# set the win size to keep the same aspect and not be related to any machine you run this on
# set size is measured in pixels
driver.set_window_size(1200, 600)

# use only to check if the win size was correctly set
win_size = driver.get_window_size()

source = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#column-a")
target = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#column-b")
# get the size of the element to be dragged not actually required but is a personal preference to make it more fancy
# and make sure the drag / drop action starts from the middle of the element
element_size = source.size

# get the location of elements in pixels
source_location = source.location
target_location = target.location

# required to get because the location of elements does not take in consideration the address bar, bookmark bar
# ie"the browser is controled by automated etc..." and the specific window size
inner_width = driver.execute_script("return window.innerWidth;")
inner_height = driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight;")

# get the offset and middle of the element to be dragged and the target
offset_width = win_size['width'] - inner_width + element_size['width'] / 2
offset_height = win_size['height'] - inner_height + element_size['height'] / 2

# ### Print Statememts used for Debbug ###
# print(f"actual size is {win_size} ,ineer size is {inner_width}, {inner_height}")
# print(source_location, target_location)
# print(element_size, f"the offsets are {offset_width} and {offset_height}")

# use pyautoguy to perform the actions
# make the actual start location by adding element .location value with the offests that are calculated for Chrome
pyautogui.moveTo(source_location['x'] + offset_width, source_location['y'] + offset_height)
pyautogui.mouseDown()

# adjust duration for a faster or slower animation for drag and drop based on preference
pyautogui.moveTo(target_location['x'] + offset_width, target_location['y'] + offset_height, duration=1)
pyautogui.mouseUp()

# ###  Assertion to check in case you don't want to look and just run the test ###
# ###  Find the moved item, get the new location  ###
# ###  Assert that initial location and location after move are not the same => Drag and Drop action is a success  ###
source_moved = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="column"]/header[text()="A"]')
source_newlocation = source_moved.location
assert source_location != source_newlocation

# add a sleep time to enjoy the fruits of the work
time.sleep(1)

driver.quit()
```

this is my code with comments
after extensive testing i found only one issue that can occur if you have display scaling set to more or less than 100% it can alter the starting points for drag and drop , other that this i did not found any issue with this code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code is clear your issue in Java

```java
public class darganddropTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/droppable/");

System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size());

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("demo-frame")));

driver.findElement(By.id("draggable")).click();

Actions a = new Actions(driver);

WebElement drag = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));

WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable"));

a.dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform();

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

}

}
```