# how to add jQuery click event using xPath?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath

### Html

```
<div id="slideit">
 <a href="javaScript:void(0)">google</a>
</div>
<div>
 <p>Test</p>
</div>
<div>
 <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Right now I am working on project where some one insist to use xPath selector.

I have similar DOM structure as i mention above. I want change color of second div.

- How to use xpath selector in jQuery

Comment: You can't with the standard jQuery core.

Comment: @T.S. you answer is related to xpath. I need to use xpath ony...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14669479/4021429)

```
function _x(STR_XPATH) {
            var xresult = document.evaluate(STR_XPATH, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
            var xnodes = [];
            var xres;
            while (xres = xresult.iterateNext()) {
                xnodes.push(xres);
            }

            return xnodes;
        }
        $(_x('//div[@id="slideit"]/a[contains(@href, "javaScript:void(0)")]/..//following-sibling::div[1]')).css({
            'color': 'red'
        });
```