# jQuery select N-th children without type code manually

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery code.

```
$('#keywords').find('input').each(function () {
  if ('-1' != $(this).val().indexOf(ui.item.label)) {
    alert($(this).val());
    $(this).closest('.row').next().children().children().children().val('');
  }
});
```

I wonder if I can make some shorthand for triple `.children()` in case I do not "know" class or id of this elem.

Comment: try to make it via XPath.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453269/jquery-select-element-by-xpath
let me know if you need an example

Comment: use `:nth-child(n)` n starts at 1

Comment: So you want to get element in level 3? Like `div > div > div` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you want to find `<i>` tag in following structure.

```
<div class="row">
</div>
<div>
 <div>
  <span>
    <i>
       Hello Selector
    </i>
  </span>

 </div>
</div>
```

You can use following script

```
$(function(){

    var text = $(".row").next().find("div span i").text();
    console.log(text);
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6w0d3om2/1/)**

Comment: You have an extra period before `next()` and `li` in the find selector should just be `i`, (or vice versa,but there's no `ul` :P). I couldn't edit due to six character limit, but please consider correcting these.