# Set parent style via child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's say I have the following `<ul>`:

```
<ul>
    <li>Child</li>
    <li><span class="active">Child</span></li>
    <li>Child</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible for me to change the style of the `<li>` via the `active` `<span>`?

E.g.:

```
.active:parent(li) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I've been able to achieve this with jQuery, but it flickers on the screen for a split second (waiting for the DOM to load) and I want to avoid that.

Comment: There is no such thing as a parent selector in CSS3, I think there would be no other way than to use javascript.

Comment: just use the active class on your li...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `has()`:

```css
li:has(> .active) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

---

<strike>There's no way to do this in CSS.</strike>

The best thing to do would be to do something like:

```
<ul class="has-active">
    <li>Child</li>
    <li><span class="active">Child</span></li>
    <li>Child</li>
</ul>
```

And style

```
ul.has-active  {
    ...
}
```

If you are looking for something that can do parent selectors, then look at something like [xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453269/jquery-select-element-by-xpath).

Comment: wut? there's no li.active on your HTML to apply that CSS rule

Comment: This code works fine to style child. The question it was how to style parent with child given.

Comment: the right answer it's to use :has pseudo class see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: @xargr 's answer is soooo much under-appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> This is impossible with pure CSS because it can't go backwards.

You must use Javascript or jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').has('.active').css('background-color','yellow');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>Child</li>
    <li><span class="active">Child</span></li>
    <li>Child</li>
</ul>
```