# Select target="_blank" when img is not a child

Tags: css, less

I have the following styling setup to apply an icon to external links, but I'm having an issue where it's applying to images that are a child of the anchor tag, which I do not want.

```
a:not(.btn) {
  &[target="_blank"] {
    &:after {
       // The styles I want to apply
    }
  }
}
```

I've attempted to use the following `img:not(:first-child)` selector to wrap the block, but it does not seem to do what I want it to.

```
a:not(.btn) {
  &[target="_blank"] + img:not(:first-child) {
    &:after {
       // The styles I want to apply
    }
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to adjust this code where it will correctly apply to any anchor tags with `target="_blank"` but not to those when an `img` tag is a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy to add a dash of javascript, you can achieve the effect you're after relatively straightforwardly by:

- adding a `class` to *all* anchor elements with `target="_blank"`
- removing the same `class` (the one you just added) from *all* parent nodes of image elements

---

**Working Example:**

```js
// GET ALL THE ANCHORS WITH target="_blank"
const anchorTargetBlanks = [...document.querySelectorAll('[target="_blank"]')];

// ADD A CLASS TO ALL SUCH ANCHORS
anchorTargetBlanks.forEach(anchor => anchor.classList.add('link-contains-no-image'));

// REMOVE THAT CLASS FROM THE PARENT NODE OF EACH IMAGE
[...document.images].forEach((image) => {
  
  if (image.parentNode.getAttribute('target') === '_blank') {
    image.parentNode.classList.remove('link-contains-no-image');
  }

});
```

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  margin: 1px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 191);
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.link-contains-no-image {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank"><img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'/%3E" alt="Image for Link 2" />Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">Link 4</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank"><img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'/%3E" alt="Image for Link 5" />Link 5</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">Link 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is target a parent based on its child, and that is not possible with CSS. You need to use JS or JQuery. Check these answers for more detailed suggestions.

[Set parent style via child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676386/set-parent-style-via-child) or
[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Ah yes, this is my bad. I think I got confused with the usage of :not. Thanks!