# JQuery to find element

Tags: jquery, selenium

Given this xpath syntax

```
//div[@class="sk-circle-container"]
```

Can somebody convert it to find the div that has attr class `sk-circle-container` in the entire DOM as JQuery script?

This seems to not find anything, even if the element is there: `div:contains(sk-circle-container)`

Comment: If your looking for a div with `sk-circle-container` as class then use `div.sk-circle-container` `$('div.sk-circle-container')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453269/jquery-select-element-by-xpath

Comment: @Carsten, it returns the following error : `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @michael the error says it all. You are missing `)` closing bracket in your code just check the console which line is it referring it to - :)

Comment: @Sebasaenz Did what the post desbribed but, when running `self.browser.execute_script('$(document).xpath("//div[@class="sk-circle-container"]");')` the following error is returned `selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @Carsten, this is what is executed, no `)` is missing : `return jQuery('div.sk-circle-container $('div.sk-circle-container')').is(':animated');`

Comment: might not be missing a `)` but is definetly broken.

Comment: Seems like it..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
driver.get(" https://www.XYZXYZXYZ.com/");

List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sk-circle-container']"));
```

OR

```
    List<WebElement> myList = driver.findElements(By.className("sk-circle-container"));
ListIterator<WebElement> myListIterat= myList.listIterator();
```