# Remove Element Found with Xpath in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xpath, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome Extension. Trying to remove a HTML element which contains certain text. Have found the element using Xpath. But the element doesn't remove, and there is no error message.

```
<div>
     <div>Some Text</div>
</div>

let element = document.evaluate("/*[text() = 'Some Text']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
element.remove();
```

This runs, but the element is not deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
let element = document.evaluate("/*[text() = 'Some Text']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null)
```

to

```
let element = document.evaluate("//*[text() = 'Some Text']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null)
element.singleNodeValue.remove()
```

and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

`document.evaluate` does not return a DOM-node. It returns an `XPathResult`. See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate).

Also see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453269/jquery-select-element-by-xpath) for guidance on how to use JQuery with XPath.